# Ajax function in javascript is not working in mozilla firefox browser, why?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Follownig is my javascript code, ajax function is used to read response from 
    server. but xmlhttp.status is always 0 in firefox browser, why? please help me.

```
        function ajaxAsyncRequest() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            //creating asynchrounous GET request

            var tempValUrl = $(".urlVal").val();
            var urls = tempValUrl + '/Department/departmentAdminTokenReceive';
            xmlhttp.open("GET", urls, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

                    alert("readyState"+xmlhttp.readyState);
                    alert("status"+xmlhttp.status);
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                        var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        //for signing
                        var signarr = data.split("$$");
                        //for signing 
                        document.getElementById('signName').value = signarr[1];
                        document.getElementById('signCertName').value = signarr[2];
                        document.getElementById('signCa').value = signarr[3];   
                        document.getElementById('signExpiryDate').value = signarr[4];
                        document.getElementById('signPublicKey').value = signarr[5];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are tons of reasons about being status 0. Is there any other relevant info you can give us to help you understand the problem? is that working in other browsers? if so, what is the request in the network tab? is there any console error thrown? Is `tempValUrl` in the same server / domain?

Comment: Yes it is working in chrome and IE browser. and Yes, tempValUrl is in the same server.

Comment: any error shown in the console? It's quite strange that it works in IE and not in Firefox.

Comment: No errors but ajax is not receiving response from server. and xmlhttp.status is 0.

Comment: Check the developer console -> network tab in firefox. Check whether the request is actually performed. If so, check the headers and response.

Comment: Okay. Thank You..